# How to create a constructor?

Tags: java, computer-science

I have this code:

```
public class BigVic extends Looper
{
    private int itsNumFilled; // count this's filled slots
    private int itsNumEmpty; // count this's non-filled slots

    public BigVic() // constructor
    { 
        // left as an exercise
    } //======================


    /** Tell how many of the executor's slots are filled. */

    public int getNumFilled()
    { 
        return itsNumFilled;
    } //======================


    /** Tell how many of the executor's slots are empty. */

    public int getNumEmpty()
    { 
        return itsNumEmpty;
    } //======================


    /** Do the original putCD(), but also update the counters. */

    public void putCD()
    { 
        if ( ! seesCD() && stackHasCD())
        {   
            itsNumFilled++;
            itsNumEmpty--;
            super.putCD();
        }
    } //======================


    /** Do the original takeCD(), but also update the counters. */

    public void takeCD()
    { 
        if (seesCD())
        { 
            itsNumFilled--;
            itsNumEmpty++;
            super.takeCD();
        }
    } //======================
}
```

And I am supposed to do this:

> Write out the `BigVic` constructor that is needed.

I managed to come up with this:

```
public BigVic()
{
    super();
    this.putCD();
    this.takeCD();
}
```

How do I answers the question? I am not sure what I could do besides adding what I already have in the constructor that would make it complete? Is what I have in it already what I need?

Comment: Hint: The constructor is usually used to initialize the variables in the class.

Comment: So the only thing missing from my constructor is `getNumFilled()` and `getNumEmpty()`? That sound right to you?

Comment: Getters will just return you a value, you still need to store it.  Usually it's done directly.

Comment: It seems like you must review your notes again. For example if you have `private int i;` you initialize it in the constructor with `i = 5`.

Comment: I can tell you that coding `super();` is not required - it's implied if you don't code it. As for what's *required*, you haven't given any info on that.

Comment: @Bohemian that is my problem it is telling me to complete the constructor however it is not telling me what is required to complete it. :S

Comment: I don't see the methods `seesCD()` or `stackHasCD()`

Comment: @Xbit they are in the parent class.

Comment: You need to work out what invariants apply to the fields in your class. The contructor's job is to make those invariants true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I can tell, it looks like you want to use

```
public BigVic() // constructor
{ 
    this.itsNumFilled = 0;  // Nothing is filled.
    this.itsNumEmpty = 100; // For a default size of 100 executor "slots".
} //======================
```

Comment: I am going to go with this I feel like this is right. Thanks! :D